# Subquery performance degrades with window function and filtering in main query

Tags: clickhouse

My intention was to create a view with a window function and the ability to filter outside of the view definition but the performance is too bad. Using view is similar to using subquery and I found the following:
Simple subquery with filtering in the main query works fine:

```
select * from (select *
    FROM default.service_library sl )
    where account_id = 1592301
```

If I add a window function to subquery it runs out of memory:

```
select * from (select *
    ,(sum(is_dead) over (partition by account_id, cluster_agent_id, run_id)) as is_dead2
    FROM default.service_library sl )
    where account_id = 1592301
```

Moving the filter from the main query to the subquery solves the problem:

```
select * from (select *,    
    (sum(is_dead) over (partition by account_id, cluster_agent_id, run_id)) as is_dead2
    FROM default.service_library sl where account_id = 672423)
```

plans for queries above:

```
┌─explain─────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Expression ((Projection + Before ORDER BY))         │
│   Filter ((WHERE + (Projection + Before ORDER BY))) │
│     Filter (WHERE)                                  │
│       ReadFromMergeTree (default.service_library)   │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

```
┌─explain─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Expression ((Projection + Before ORDER BY))                                             │
│   Filter ((WHERE + (Projection + Before ORDER BY)))                                     │
│     Window (Window step for window 'PARTITION BY account_id, cluster_agent_id, run_id') │
│       Sorting (Sorting for window 'PARTITION BY account_id, cluster_agent_id, run_id')  │
│         Expression (Before window functions)                                            │
│           ReadFromMergeTree (default.service_library)                                   │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

```
┌─explain───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Expression ((Projection + (Before ORDER BY + (Projection + Before ORDER BY))))        │
│   Window (Window step for window 'PARTITION BY account_id, cluster_agent_id, run_id') │
│     Sorting (Sorting for window 'PARTITION BY account_id, cluster_agent_id, run_id')  │
│       Expression (Before window functions)                                            │
│         Filter (WHERE)                                                                │
│           ReadFromMergeTree (default.service_library)                                 │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE default.service_library
(
account_id Int32,
checksum String,
cluster_agent_id Int32,
entity_guid String,
language String,
name String,
real_agent_id Int32,
version String,
created_at DateTime DEFAULT now(),
run_id Int32,
is_dead UInt8 DEFAULT 0
)
ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree(created_at)
ORDER BY (account_id, entity_guid, name, version, cluster_agent_id, real_agent_id)
```

Comment: look like in second query WHERE predicate doesn't push down
why you need subqueries here?

why just not use 
`select *
    ,(sum(is_dead) over (partition by account_id, cluster_agent_id, run_id)) as is_dead2
    FROM default.service_library sl WHERE account_id = 1592301` ?

Comment: I want to create a view with a window function and filter the results of view. Unfortunately CH optimized doesn't understand that filtering by account_id can be pushed to subquery or to query in case of a view.